# Позиция QAction*ов в QMenu

Tags: qt, c++

Как получить QPoint заданого QAction в нужном QMenu?

```
QMenu regionMenu;
...
menuAction = new QAction("a",this);             connect(menuAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(onMenuClick()));
regionMenu->addAction(menuAction);
```

Как в таком случаи получить позицию menuAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QMenu::actionGeometry](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmenu.html#actionGeometry). Открывайте документации чаще.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Я с Qt третий день)